# Why Doesnt CreateUserWizard Control automatically adds the ASPNETDB.MDF database? Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, asp

Hello I am making a webiste in asp.net in visual studio 2017 community With .NET Framework 3.5 But i have a problem When i add Create User Wizard ASPNETDB.MDF database is not created in App_Data folder What is wrong

Answer (score 0):

> You need to either create the database and tables yourself using SQL scripts that Microsoft provides - or use the aspnet_regsql.exe utility in your ASP.NET folder to create those objects for you (in whichever database you choose to create them in).

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29917669/1221410)